# Incorrect max and min in Python code

Tags: python

When I try to run this code, I get incorrect maximums and minimums. Could anyone tell me how I can fix it? I am not allowed to use 'max' and 'min'.

UPDATE: I have updated the code and it still doesn't work properly.
UPDATE 2: The code works now! Thank you so much guys!

```
minimum=float('inf')
maximum=None
count=0
total=0
number=input ("Please enter the amount of numbers you wish to categorize: ")
while True:

    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    count+=1
    total+=num

    if num is None or num < minimum:
        minimum = num

    if num is None or num > maximum:
        maximum = num
    if count == number:
        break           

print "The average of your numbers is ", round ((total / count),2),"."
print 'The largest number is:', maximum,"."
print 'The smallest number is:', minimum,"."
```

Comment: I'm assuming this is homework as you said "I am not allowed to use 'max' and 'min'". In the future, please add the `homework` tag to any homework questions.

Comment: Think about when to initialize `minimum` and `maximum`, and about the value you should use. Should it be a value _you_ provide, or should it be a value your user provides?

Comment: While we're commenting on things, you're using Python 2, in which case `/` performs truncating division (3/2 == 1).  Use `float(total)/count` or `(1.0*total/count)` or something to avoid this problem in the case of integer input.

Comment: You changed `input` to `raw_input`. `raw_input` returns a string; you have to do this to convert it to an int: `num = int(num)`. Also, as mVChr points out, your `break` statement is in the wrong place. Think about what happens if your user enters the maximum or minimum number last.

Comment: I strongly suggest to use `int(raw_input( ... ))` instead of `input`.

Comment: Oh! Also, you didn't do what Ignacio said to do. Look at his code again. It's different from yours still. Or better yet, think about why this wouldn't work. Why would `num` ever be `None` here? And what is testing for `None` supposed to achieve?

Comment: My $0.02: it would be much more fitting to use `for _ in range(0,number):` rather than `while True:` and remove the `count+=1` and `if count == number:`, etc.

Comment: Thanks, but we're learning loops now and are limited to what we were taught.

Comment: Oh, an of course it should be `if minimum is None or num < minimum:` instead of `if num is None or num < minimum:` ... that's why your code does not work. The solution with `None` is better than the `'inf'` thing, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your initial values and conditions for `minimum` and `maximum` are incorrect.

```
minimum = None
maximum = None
 ...
    if minimum is None or num < minimum:
        minimum = num

    if maximum is None or num > maximum:
        maximum = num
...
```

You could also fix this by checking if `count` equals 1 instead of identity to `None`.

Comment: I have changed this, and the maximum and minimum values are still incorrect.

Comment: @user1292009, have you read [mVChr](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9865781/577088)'s answer?

Comment: Yes, I just changed that. The maximum value is working fine now, but no matter what, the minimum value is 'None'.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what Ignacio said, you're breaking out of your loop too early.  You want to process the last number you enter before breaking, so move the `if count == number: break` block after the min/max setting blocks.

Answer (score 1):

As this is homework you're supposed to learn. Here are some ideas how to solve the problem:

One error is that you're initializing `maximum` and `minimum` to `0` on program startup. if you only type in positiv numbers minimum will stay at `0` but won't be the real minimum. To solve this case you should look into lists or initialize both variables to some values that uniquely identifies an invalid initial value that won't leak into your calculation (I suggest `None`). On the first iteration set both `minimum` and `maximum` to the first entered value.

**After modfifications**: You are comparing strings since `raw_input` returns strings, not numbers. You have to convert those strings into integer values using `int`, for example `int(raw_input( ... ))`. Additionally you had a badly indented `break` of which I fixed the indent.

**Other idea**: Since you're not allowed to use `min` and `max` you might just use

```
tmp=sorted([int(raw_input('Number: ')) for x in xrange(number)])
minimum, maximum = tmp[0], tmp[-1]
```

but I guess this defeats your assignment :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can set a number to infinity or negative infinity by

```
maximum=float('-inf')
minimum=float('inf')

print minimum, maximum
```

This might be useful for your homework ;)

Ignacio's answer would be preferable if you want to consider the case that the user enters `0` for `number` (since `None` would be a more seasonable maximum of no numbers than `-inf`).

Edit:

Remark to mVChr's correct finding:

Instead of using a `while True` loop with a `break` why not writing

```
while count < number:
```

or even use a for loop:

```
for count in xrange(number):
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that requires the least treatment of special values, would be to initialize both variables to +/- infinity.

```
minimum=float("-inf")
maximum=float("inf")
```

Comment: Python doesn't have a reasonable highest (or lowest) integer.

Comment: oh, and you must set `minimum` to `inf` and `maximum` to `-inf`; your answer always gives `-inf`, `inf` as answers